# Are definitional and propositional extenionality on top of intensional type theory equivalent?

Tags: agda, dependent-type, type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I am reading the article about [extensional type theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensional+type+theory) on n-lab and it mentions two ways to make intensional type theory extensional.

1. Definitional: Add rule `p:Id(x,y) => x===y`
2. Propositional: Add one of the following to the type theory

   - axiom UIP
   - axiom K
   - axiom stating `Id((a,b_1),(a,b_2)) => Id(b_1,b_2)` where `(a,b_1)` and `(a,b_2)` are both dependent pairs
   - add unconstrained pattern matching as in original Agda

My question is are these two ways equivalent?

Specifically, if so, can one derive `p:Id(x,y) => x===y` from axiom K or UIP?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question.

Comment: That does not mean the this question is irrelevant to programming languages. Have a look at the related questions of this one. Many of them are about type theories out of context of a specific programming language. If this question is off topic, then so are those questions. I don’t think our very conversation is constructive to this discussion of this question. So Can we delete it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tour says questions are about "specific programming problems, software algorithms, coding techniques, software development tools." Homotopy type theory doesn't seem to get any of these categories. If you can express this in terms of a problem with agda, then that would be on topic.

Comment: @protossor, while I personally do not consider this question off-topic, you might still have a better chance of getting good answers on cstheory.stackexchange.com, where such topics are more frequent.

Comment: Thank you Andreas! I didn’t know that site :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The n-lab take on what it means for a type theory to be extensional is fairly peculiar. It makes sense though if you are mostly interested in whether the `Id` type can be extended with univalence, which is not the case if you have UIP.

(1) does imply (2) (using the numbers from the question), so it's not consistent with univalence.

(1) is the rule that more traditional sources would associate with the name "extensional type theory".

However (2) does not imply (1), as canonicity for the `Id` type for a theory like Agda would show that any proof of `Id` in an empty context is reflexivity, while (1) implies function extensionality.

Comment: Thank you Saizan! By function extensionality you mean `forall x, f, g, Id(f x, g x) => Id(f, g)` right? Could you explain a bit how to get function extensionality from (1)?

Comment: Not quite, it's `forall f g, (forall x, Id(f x, g x)) => Id(f,g)`.You do it by proving that under the assumption `(forall x, Id(f x, g x))` and with `x` in scope, we have `f x = g x` definitionally, which then implies `(\x. f x) = (\x. g x)` by congruence, and finally `f = g` by eta.

Comment: Wow! congruence followed by eta! Thank you!